# String to JSON Apache CXF REST

Tags: java, json, rest, cxf

I have a class where I store the name of my application as a String:

```
public class ApplicationInformation {

   public static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "APP_XYZ";

public String getApplicationName() {
      return APPLICATION_NAME;
   }
```

Now in my RESTful class I'm calling this method:

```
public Response getApplicationName() {
  String applicationName = new ApplicationInformation().getApplicationName();
  return Response.ok(applicationName, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

}

But what I get as Result is:

```
[APP_XYZ]
```

and what I want to get is:

```
[{
  "APPLICATION_NAME":"APP_XYZ"
}]
```

Does anyone have an idea how I do that ?
I tried it with JSONObject from org.json but this wasn't helpful

I'm using APACHE CXF as REST library

Comment: Why do you want to wrap it in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`Response.ok(new ApplicationInformation(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();`

If you need to customize the JSON format you can use Jackson annotations on `ApplicationInformation` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jackson libary annotations to manipulate json response.

@JsonTypeName("ApplicationInformation")
public class ApplicationInformation 
       public static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "APP_XYZ";

```
public String getApplicationName() {
      return APPLICATION_NAME;
   }
```

this should generate a response like below

```
{
    "ApplicationInformation": {
        "APPLICATION_NAME ": "APP_XYZ"
    }
}
```